# How to include file to (vb)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have 2 files (test.vbhtml) and (page.vbhtml)

test.vbhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title>testing the database</title>
   <style>
       table, th, td {
         border: solid 1px #bbbbbb;
         border-collapse: collapse;
         padding: 2px;
       }
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1>People</h1>
   <table>
       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th>Id</th>
               <th>name</th>
               <th>lastname</th>
               <th>age</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           @for each row in db.Query(selectQueryString)
            @<tr>
               <td>@row.Id</td>
                   <td>@row.name</td>
                   <td>@row.lastname</td>
                   <td>@row.age</td>
            </tr>
           next
       </tbody>
   </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

And here is the page.vbhtml

```
@Code
Dim db = Database.Open("dall")
Dim selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM test"
Dim dbMedewerkers = "Select * FROM Medewerkers"
End Code
```

in the future the page will be much more than this.

My question is:

Is it possible to add/include page.vbhtml to test.vbhtml.

the reason I need this is not to write every connection manual.

Comment: You talking about `Layout` views [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout)

Comment: the code you've shown for page.vbhtml consists entirely of code for querying the database, so maybe it's not an include, maybe it's part of your model code (or even an deeper layer of the app). Then you feed the data to the app via a model or Viewmodel. Work through the MS tutorials to see how to structure an MVC app https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started. The way you're structuring it now is basically the ASP Classic mentality of includes and inline scripting, which has been obsolete since about 2001.

Comment: @ADyson The vbhtml is just an example (and indeed thats code for quering) but what if i have an page with code that i want to use on other pages how do i achief ( i need something like an include on html (but for vb) )

Comment: Well it depends what the code is. If it's some shared stuff to fetch data, or make calculations about business rules, it doesn't belong in a page at all, it belongs somewhere in the code-behind - in a model, viewmodel, data layer or other library class. If it's snippets of markup that you want to re-use on different pages, then Partial Views or Templates are the way go. If it's markup that all pages must display, then use a Layout page (you can nest these, for flexibility). If it's shared script or style, then include separate JS and CSS files just as in basic HTML.

Comment: ...If you follow the tutorial I suggested, and others like it, it will introduce all these concepts. You need to get the hang of how an MVC .NET app is structured and all the potential moving parts, and then you will understand enough to know the answer these kinds of questions in each situation you encounter. There are multiple ways to "include" code in an application like this, and the best way to do it depends on the type and purpose of the code, it's much more complicated than a basic HTML page.